# Call API from another API in Azure

Tags: javascript, api, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to call API from another one in mobile services using JavaScript, but getting this error:

> Error in script '/api/*api_name*.js'. TypeError: Object function (response) {
>   [external code]
>       at exports.post.httpRequest.get.mssql.query.success.mssql.query.success (D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\config\scripts\api\*api_name*.js:49:36)
>       [external code]

API (where I call another API function):

```
var api_name = require('../api/*api_name*.js');

exports.post = function(request, response) {
    api_name.post(request, function(response) {
        console.log("test")
    })
};
```

Also, I have no problem calling *api_name*.js using iOS Azure SDK.

So, I can't figure out how to call one JS API from another.

It would be great if anyone could explain me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that your custom API name does not contain the '*' character and that you've replaced the actual name of the custom API with '*api_name*' - you cannot use wildcard characters in the names of modules loaded with require.

While it should be possible to require another API module directly, it is recommended that you refactor the common code out to a shared module. Place this in the /shared folder of your site and reference the module using the following syntax:

```
var sharedModule = require('../shared/sharedModule');
```

If you need to pass custom success or error handlers, you could do something like:

api/api1.js

```
var shared = require('../shared/sharedModule');

exports.get = function(request, response) {
    shared(request, response, 'table1', function(results) {
        if(results.length == 1)
            response.send(200, results[0]);
        }
    });
};
```

api/api2.js

```
var shared = require('../shared/sharedModule');

exports.get = function(request, response) {
    shared(request, response, 'table2', function(results) {
        if(results.length == 5)
            response.send(200, "Correct number of records");
        else
            response.send(400, "Incorrect number of records");
    });
};
```

shared/sharedModule.js

```
module.exports = function (request, response, table, success) {
    request.service.mssql.query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + table, {
        success: success,
        error: function (error) {
            response.send(500, error);
        }
    });
}
```

This uses the same error handler for each invocation, you could also pass a custom error handler each time.

Comment: Thank you for response, Dale! Actually I thought about it, however I need this invoked api exactly as api with the success/error response and so on.

So, there is no way to invoke api from another one, isn't it?

Comment: You should still be able to call require('./api_name') and execute the exported functions directly. For example, if you have two files in the api folder, one called `api1.js` and the other `api2.js`, you should be able to do something like

    var api1 = require('./api1.js');
    api1.post(request, response);

Comment: Thank you, it works, but, actually, I need to handle success/failure blocks of invoked api, is it possible?

Comment: Does the sample I added above give you an idea of how to approach this?